# how to get attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I am running following html code for each one minute using set timeout

```
<div data-id='1' class="userId">
    <span> user name-1 </span>
</div>
<div data-id='2' class="userId">
    <span>user name-2</span>
</div>
```

for the first time i can take value from all data-id by using..

**javascript:**

```
var userIds = $('.userId').map(function(){     
  return $(this).data('id');
}).get();
```

But second time means after 1 minute it throws undefined.

Please help me to correct my wrong..

Comment: `But second time means after 1 minute it throws undefined.` Would you explain that how come?

Comment: @abhi Instead of putting "." in your question , you could have accepted Vega's answer?

Answer (score 6):

```
                    //  V-- missing dot
```

Change `$('userId')` to `$('.userId')`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9RDDy/

> But second time means after 1 minute it throws undefined.

Did you remove `$('.userId')` when calling it second time? It should work if those elements exist when you call it second time.

Comment: @Vega thanks for the answer.. by mistake i missed the dot i edited the code

Comment: @Vega -- first time fine but failing in second time

Comment: @abhi Did you remove `$('.userId')` before calling it second time? It should work if those elements exist when you call it second time.

Comment: @abhi Can you produce that in fiddle?